# More terse way to write these nginx location rules?

Tags: nginx

I have tried to rewrite the following Nginx locations rules to a single location block, but because of the (.*)$ it seems to be evading me..

```
 location ~ /admin {
    rewrite   ^/admin(.*)$ /target.php last;
 }

 location ~ /index/ {
    rewrite   ^/index/(.*)$ /target.php last;
 }

 location ~ /services/ {
    rewrite   ^/services/(.*)$ /target.php last;
 }

 location ~ /test/ {
    rewrite   ^/test/(.*)$ /target.php last;
 }
```

I have been able to use regex before, but couldn't get the approach below fit the above

```
 location ~ /(someplace|other|another)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always target.php (and where is $1? ):

```
location ~ /(test|services|index)/ {
    rewrite   ^/*/(.*)$ /target.php last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. $1 gets ignored here because the FastCGI - which ultimately services the rewrite - uses $request_uri for onward decision making